# How to delete Python on mac completely?

Tags: macos, mac, python, python3

I want to download only the latest version of Python and get rid of the old ones. I already deleted all the old ones I downloaded before. But when I check for Python versions in my terminal or import libraries it is still working for some reason.

Comment: Is the installed version of Python listed within Applications?

Comment: No, it's not. I deleted it from trash as well.

Comment: Please be aware that parts of macOS depend on Python themselves, so completely removing Python could break macOS. It's been generally considered best practice for many years now to leave the "system Python" (the version of Python built into macOS) alone, and install your own separate Python installation if you need to use Python for your own purposes (or if some other software you're using needs Python). So feel free to delete Python installations you've made yourself, but you'd be wise to leave the system Python alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may uninstall Python manually from the Application folder, then check
all possible folders for its traces. But the list of possible folders
is pretty long.

I would suggest to use
[App Cleaner & Uninstaller](https://nektony.com/mac-app-cleaner)
to do the job for you.
The evaluation version has a trial period of 3 days, so this will be
a one-time effort.

The list of folders to check manually is found in the article
[Uninstall Python on Mac](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-python-on-mac).
You will also find in this article more information about using the
App Cleaner & Uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dlzi/c2cb7e39835cb2da868de47394cd4e83) with a few simple commands that remove the "Python Releases for macOS"/"Python Launcher.app" Python versions while not touching the macOS default version in `/usr/bin/python3`.

Below is [the GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dlzi/c2cb7e39835cb2da868de47394cd4e83) quoted in its entirety at the time of writing for easy reference.

**Note that you must change the version number** in the below commands to match whatever version of Python Releases for macOS you have installed (you can find them by looking in the `/Applications` directory.)

> **1. DO NOT attempt to remove any Apple-supplied system Python which are in `/System/Library` and `/usr/bin`.**
> **2. Multiple Python versions can coexist pacifically on macOS. So, uninstalling Python is purely optional.**
>
> To remove a different version, change `3.7` to the Python version you
> want to remove.
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7
> ```
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 3.7"
> ```
>
> ```
> sudo find /usr/local/bin -lname '../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/*' -delete
> ```